How to make a scatter plot in Netlogo
Im trying to see changes in distribution by using two variables from the agents (money and culture)
Im putting this directly on the plot, selecting points mode.
plotxy [economic] of turtles [cultural] of turtles.

However, Im getting this error:
PLOTXY expected input to be a number but got the list [] instead

I know that the list is not empty, I need one point in the graph for each turtle

plotxy only takes 2 numbers as input. If you want to plot multiple points you need to do this in a loop. For turtles, you can do it with ask, e.g. :
ask turtles [plotxy xcor ycor]

or in your case:
ask turtles [plotxy economic cultural]

Make sure, you set the Mode of the pen to point!

Hello! It worked thankyou very much. Wanted to ask you if there is a way to measure the distance of the points to the 0 , 0 coordinate (both economic and cultural go from -10 to 10)

To ask a new question, please open a new question
